# Get warning when convert double to NSDecimalNumber

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods, double, nsdecimalnumber

I'm trying to convert a `double` to an `NSDeciamlNumber`. Here is my code:

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)myMethod {
    double amount = 42;
    ...

    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:amount]; // Get warning here
}
```

But I get the following warning:

> `Incompatible pointer types returning 'NSNumber *' from a function with result type 'NSDecimalNumber *'`

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numberWithDouble: method of NSDecimalNumber returns NSNumber.
In your method you want to return decimal so its OK if you allocate a new NSDecimalNumber with the decimal value (amount in your example).

May use the following way to get rid of the error:

```
-(NSDecimalNumber *)myMethod 
{ double amount = 42; ...
    return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble: amount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:_] returns a NSNumber so you should change the method declaration

```
- (NSNumber *)myMethod {
    double amount = 42;
    ...

    return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:amount]; // Get warning here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may work out

```
- (NSNumber *)myMethod {
   double amount = 42;
   [NSNumber numberWithDouble:amount]
  return [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:amount]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`numberWithDouble:` method returns an NSNumber object but you suppose to return NSDecimalNumber.

Change it to

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)myMethod {
    double amount = 42;

    return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc]initWithDouble:amount];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code-

```
- (NSDecimalNumber *)myMethod {
    double amount = 42;
    ...

    return [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithDouble: amount]; 
}
```